# Magento 2: How to display region label instead of option value in custom ui component grid?

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, ui-form

I have created an ui component and form. In the form, I have added the country and region fields and in the grid, I need to display the region label instead of the option value. How to achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

UI component

```
<column name="region_id" class="[Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\Component\[Entity]\Listing\Columns\RegionLabel">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Region</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Create a custom UI component column in your module. For example, create a file named regionLabel.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\Component\[Entity]\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class RegionLabel extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\Region
     */
    protected $regionModel;

    /**
     * RegionLabel constructor.
     *
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\Region $regionModel
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Region $regionModel,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->regionModel = $regionModel;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Replace region_id value with its label in each row of the grid
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $regionId = $item[$this->getData('name')];
                $region = $this->regionModel->load($regionId);
                $regionLabel = $region->getDefaultName();
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $regionLabel;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

I hope it will work for you.

Thanks !!